# Downloading large files from ChemAxon on Windows 7, how do I ensure the entire file is downloaded?

Tags: windows-7, download

I frequently update installations of ChemAxon freeware on my PC and to do so I need to download large (>200 MB ea) executable (.exe) files from their website. My problem is that these downloads always seem to get cut off before all the file has been transferred. For example, if I download these files in Google Chrome I seldom get any more than 20 MB of the file before it quits due to some unknown error. This problem seems common to all Internet browsers on my PC (including Firefox and Opera). I thought I had this problem solved when I got wget to work on my PC (which I installed via cygwin) as it seemed to get the job done when web browsers failed, but unfortunately recently (past ~3 days approximately) I have noticed wget has also failed to download ChemAxon files completely, with connection errors cited as the cause (even though my internet connection seems fine). Wget usually manages to get to ~70-80% the way before it quits. I am mentioning ChemAxon specifically as I have downloaded other large files these past three days in Chrome and via wget from other websites, without a problem. If you are interested here's the exact error wget gives:

```
2015-04-13 17:54:28 (51.0 KB/s) - Connection closed at byte 261711437. Giving up.
```

Comment: sure its not the file/server? tried wget -c (so you can continue?)

Comment: Yup, wget -c or just about any download manager as long as the server supports resuming (which only ancient ones don't, or newer ones that specifically prevent it for some reason such as for free users of file locker sites).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to download these files use one of these commands:

```
wget -c -i Downloads.txt -p DEST
```

or

```
wget -c URL -p DEST
```

where `URL` is the download URL and `DEST` is the destination of the downloads (e.g., `C:\Users\Brenton\Downloads`). The file `Downloads.txt` should be in the directory you're running wget from and should contain all URLs you wish to download files from.